# How to recover the share data sources in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I am having some trouble with my reports, accidentally I deleted the share data sources and now my reports are not running and I have around 400 reports. How to recover the share data source.

I have the backup of the reportserver and the reportservertempDB which I restored but it still doesnot shows up.

Can anyone knows how to get the deleted data sources?

Thank you!!!!!

Comment: A data source is basically just a connection string to a DB & Server.  Can you not just re-add manually or did you delete lots of shared data sources?

Comment: I have 10 data sources and I deleted all

Comment: I don't know of a way to recover them (there may well be one) but 10 is not many to add back in.  Your LOCAL datasources should still exist and if you have good naming convention, should give you some idea which DB/Servers you need to point your shared DSs at.

Comment: Open the report project(s) in BIDS and redeploy the shared data sources to the server.

Comment: Depending on how you created them, you could just go back the the solution/project and redeploy them.